# My pdf is blank when trying to extracting report from MS access using python

Tags: python, ms-access, pdf-generation, blank-line

When I am running below `python` code, its generating `PDF` file with blank pages.
Although I am expecting it to generate `PDF` file as it's saved on `MS Access` report.

Can someone please let me know what I'm missing.

Below is my code

```
import win32com.client as win
import os
import time

s_current_working_directory = os.getcwd()    
script = os.path.realpath(__file__)

def file_open(file_name):
    if os.path.exists(file_name):
        try:
            os.rename(file_name, file_name) 
            return False
        except:
            print("File Open "+file_name)
            time.sleep(2)
            file_open(file_name)
            return True
    else:
        return False
    raise NameError

access = win.Dispatch("Access.Application")
access.visible = 1
db = access.OpenCurrentDatabase(os.path.join(s_current_working_directory, 'Database.accdb'))  
access.DoCmd.OpenReport('ReportName',1)

if os.path.isfile(filename):
    os.remove(filename)

access.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, 'ReportName', r'PDF Format (*.pdf)', r'export_path')
access.DoCmd.CloseDatabase
access.Quit()
access=None
```

Comment: I presume there is an actual report name in place of `ReportName` and an actual path in place of `export_path`. Why are arguments preceded with an `r`?

Comment: Yes, ReportName and export_path is being replaced by actual path. Example: 
'access.DoCmd.OutputTo(3, 'R_XYZ', r'PDF Format (*.pdf)', r'C:/Users/username/test.pdf')'
An ‘r’ preceding a string denotes a raw, (almost) un-escaped string.